# Deploy website on azure virtual machine and access on internet

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, windows-server-2016

I want to deploy a website on azure IIS by using server 2016(Azure VM), and want to access it anywhere on the internet. How can I do this?
Which ip address I've to use for this purpose?

Comment: there are tens of articles online about this

Answer (score 5):

There are several steps to acheive this deployment on IIS.

**1.Install IIS on azure VM.**

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/set-up-iis-on-windows-virtual-machine/

**2.Create a website for publish**

Please remember to grant permission for authenticated user like IUSR and application pool identity

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site

**3.Set Azure VM firewall to allow your port like 80**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

**4.Publish your website.**

You could achieve this via simple copy action in Remote desktop or VS web deployment
Just ensure your website can be accessed via telnet or tcping.exe. I remember ping is blocked by Azure VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio

**5.Try to access from both internal IP address and external firewall IP address.**

If you could access from internal IP which means your IIS site has been built correctly.
If the website can be access from external. Then you have finished the publish.

**6.If you want to access website from public domain.**

Then you have to purchase domain name from public domain provider. Then bind your domain to your public IP address on their portal. As long as the website can be accessed from external. It would work with domain name.